# LXDE won't run on Ubuntu Studio 19.10! Installed but after reboot, it immediately starts XFCE

Tags: xfce, desktop-environments, lxde, ubuntu-studio

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 19.10 on a Toshiba Satellite, and I wanted to try a different environment, and decided on LXDE because I'm looking to save even more hardware usage.
Regardless of that, I was under the impression that I only had to run `sudo apt install lxde lxde-common lxsession-logout` and reboot the laptop and I'd have a prompt to use LXDE over XFCE; yet, no prompt was made when I rebooted.

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing? Or is it that LXDE won't run on Ubuntu Studio 19.10?

Is there anything I need to change in a setting or something else I'd need to install?

Comment: You select the desktop on the logon screen; exactly how depends on the greeter in use. I don;t know what Studio uses, if you [edit] your question and show what the logon screen looks like, I can probably answer.

Comment: No logon screen, I've set it in automatic logon; do I need to set it as "ask for a password"?

Comment: I really have no idea how to remove the option to auto logon, I dunno where it is in XFCE

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot help with XFCE because I have no experience with it. Perhaps you could post another question about removing auto login in XFCE.